# Why is my web scraping script so slow?

Tags: php, performance, http, scrapy

My script, which is a web scraping script, is very slow, I even needed to put set_time_limit(0);

This is the whole http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9qt-78n

I think the problem is here:

```
foreach ($array_with_links as $url_job) {

$info=Array(getTitle($url_job, getID($url_job)), getTitle_Short($url_job, getID($url_job)), getCity($url_job), 
 getDepartment($url_job), getSalary($url_job), getJobNumber($url_job), getPositionStartDate($url_job), getFullTimeEquivalent($url_job),
  getPermTermCasual($url_job), getLocation($url_job), getQualifications($url_job), getDuties($url_job), 
  getClosingDate($url_job), getContact($url_job), getEmail($url_job), getCreated_On($url_job), getID($url_job) );

array_push($data, $info);}
```

Example of some of those functions:

```
function getCity($url)
    {
    $url = curl_get_contents($url);
    $html_object = str_get_html($url);
    return $ret = $html_object->find('td', 86)->plaintext;
    }

function getDepartment($url)
    {
    $url = curl_get_contents($url);
    $html_object = str_get_html($url);
    return $ret = $html_object->find('td', 90)->plaintext;
    }
```

And this is my cURL funtion:

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
  $curl_moteur = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  curl_setopt($curl_moteur,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

  curl_setopt($curl_moteur, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $web = curl_exec($curl_moteur);
  curl_close($curl_moteur);
  return $web;
}
```

Those getX come from an URL one by one.  Maybe is there any method to make multiple simultaneous insertions in that array?

I really don't know what to do and what's my mistake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that every one of your `getCity()`, `getDepartment()` etc functions loads the same web page over and over.

You should load each URL once with your `curl_get_contents()`, then pass its result into each `get*()` function to parse it.

Comment: I believe you just hit the bullseye! Spot on! Nailed it!

Comment: str_get_html is also called repeatedly.

Comment: that's it!!! so, how can I implement a cache system in order to extract all the information fields requesting each url just one time

Comment: @user204415 Invoke `curl_get_contents` and `str_get_html` only once at the start of your `foreach` loop, and pass `$html_object` instead of `$url` as the parameter to each of your `getXXX` functions.

Comment: @user204415 you are right sir.